# Javascript: replace a string in element.src attribute

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, replace

Hi I am currently trying to replace a query string value in a a link's src attribute.

it works fine in firefox but not in ie.

example:

```
<a id="link" href="#" src="http://somedomain.com?id=123&size=20">link</a>
```

then on my js it looks kinda like this:

```
var link = document.getElementById('link');
link.src.replace('size=20', 'size=45');
```

in ie, it returns something like src is not an object error;

anyone kind enough to lend a hand?

also, i need this to be on native javascript so please don't suggest a framework as a solution thanks.

Comment: You might also want is use the Regex with replace, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 1):

To get it to work in IE you're going to need to use `link.setAttribute('src', ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
var link = document.getElementById('link');
var src = link.getAttribute("src").replace('size=20', 'size=45');
link.setAttribute("src", src);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, links ([anchor elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A)) don't have a src attribute, I think that you want to change the href attribute:

```
var link = document.getElementById('link');
link.href = link.href.replace('size=20', 'size=45');
```

Comment: Good point. Though he could be using src as a custom attribute, in which case setAttribute and getAttribute come back into play.

Comment: well yeah sorry bout that, i used a wrong example (im really fussed lol)... in my real case, its an img tag... im trying to display gravatar images... on preview i use smaller thumbnails hence the s=18 query string. but on click, i want to replace the s=18 with s=45 and place the result on a textbox.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the "src" attribute in your link is an expando attribute, since an anchor tag does not have a src.

When working with expando attributes, it's safest to set and get the values using the **setAttribute(**'attributeName'**,***value***)** and **getAttribute(**'attributeName'**)** accessors.

To find out more about getAttribute and setAttribute you can check here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute

To find out more about DHTML properties you can check the MSDN Resource here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533055%28VS.85%29.aspx

Example Code using getAttribute and setAttribute:

```
var link = document.getElementById('link');
var src = link.getAttribute('src');
link.setAttribute('src',src.replace('size=20','size=40'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe getAttribute is more cross-browser friendly.

```
var link = document.getElementById('link');
var result = link.getAttribute("src").replace('size=20', 'size=45');
```

Also, the replace function returns a string. It doesn't operate on the string it is called against. This means you have to assign the result.

```
link.setAttribute("src", result);
```